# Does WCF break if the method name ends with "Response"?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I've come across a very weird problem that had me stumped for most of the day, and I don't fully believe this is the cause, but I can reproduce it:

If you have a WCF service with a method called something like "GetFormForResponse", when you call it it seems to get confused and throws errors saying that the method cannot be found (but the service compiles, so evidently it is there!).

Also, it was doing the same thing even if the WCF method name did NOT end with "Response", but within the method was a call to a function ending with "Response".

Just seems too weird to be true, but renaming the methods so they do not end with "Response" has done the trick. Am I mad?

Comment: I suspect that you accidentally fixed the problem while you were renaming rather than the problem being the Method name containing response.  I have plenty of methods that use the word Response as part of the method name.

Comment: WCF does have a problem with "Response" as a suffix on a class name. If a method is named "Method" having a class named "MethodResponse" makes it very upset when you generate the WCF client code.

Comment: @Chad I was thinking that too but literally all I changed was the method names, and I took another method in the same service which was working perfectly, changed the names to end with "Response" and it did exactly the same thing. It seems to have something to do with the code being executed within the method too... basically none of it makes sense but thought I'd throw it out there to see if anyone had seen anything similar...

Comment: Change the method name in the interface class, and change it accordingly in the class. Run the service and update the service reference in the client, then see what happens.

Comment: @Chad I don't believe it shows up in the official WCF documentation. If I'm recalling correctly, I only had trouble with the WCF clients generated by Visual Studio. There's more info about the issue here: http://geekswithblogs.net/LeonidGaneline/archive/2008/06/02/wcf-data-contract-names-dont-use-names-with-response-suffix.aspx

Comment: @Flz'Zen - You should make that an answer.

Comment: OK after more investigation and hair-pulling I think it's something more to do with caching or versioning, as it now seems to come and go at random... If it's not working I start putting debug code in, then it will suddenly start working and I can undo all the debug code and it will still work in the state it was in originally... @Fls'Zen that is interesting, but I think my problem must be something else after all. Thanks all for your input

Comment: @RossJ - I have seen that a lot.  Delete the obj and bin debug directories prior to build to force the rebuild.  You can tell if it didnt take when you are debugging because it will not load your debug symbols(breakpoints) for changed code.

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a try,  a web service defined by:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
  [OperationContract]
  string GetData(int value);

  [OperationContract]
  string GetDataResponse(int value);
}
```

works. Both methods can be called as expected.